# Filtering markers assigns new IDs to them

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Im trying to build a map where the user can filter the markers using some properties of the GeoJSON object. The filter works ok, the problem is each time I apply a filter the markers are assigned with new IDs, as you can see in the console when running the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/lmartins/z8wBW/

The way im applying the filter is essentially as described in the Mapbox examples:

```
$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
    // For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    systemLocations.setFilter(function(f) {
        // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
        // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
        // a value set to true based on the filter name.
        return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
    });


    return false;
});
```

The Mapbox example can be found here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-with-multiple-filters/

Any way I can avoid the markers IDs from being changed?

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer: just don't change them. How do you generate identifiers? Can they be inherited from GeoJSON data?

Comment: Im not changing them, it's the library that is doing that. But your comment left me wondering if there's a way to manually assign ids. Maybe in that case they wouldn't change. I'll look into it.

Comment: Did you try something like `onEachFeature: function(f, l) { l._fid = f.id; }`? (Sorry for not reading into your code on jsfiddle)

Comment: @IljaZverev yes, my solutions ended up being repeating that function, essentially rebuilding the featureLayer whenever the filters are changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ilja suggests, Leaflet ids are an internal detail - anything prefixed with a `_` in the Leaflet library means that it's not part of the external API and not something you can count on staying stable. Filtering markers removes and recreates layers and thus will change the ids. The best route would be to add IDs in your GeoJSON data directly and to rely on them.

Comment: I ended up doing something simpler, essentially rebuilding the featureLayer when filters updated. Tks.